# What is the advantage and disadvantage store data without create proper table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Normally If I want to store data, I create this type of table

```
id | name | age | salary
1  | john | 20  | 2000
2  | Jess | 18  | 1500
```

But If I store these data like this,

```
id | user_id | field_name | field_value
1  | 1       | name       | john        
2  | 1       | age        | 20
3  | 1       | salary     | 2000 
4  | 2       | name       | Jess        
5  | 2       | age        | 18
6  | 2       | salary     | 1500
```

1. what is the advantages?
2. what is the disadvantages?
3. Is it good practice?

please someone advise me? thank you...

Comment: If you're going that route, you probably want to look into a [NoSQL database](http://nosql-database.org/).

Comment: I can't think of any advantages, but would point out 2 distadvantages. Firstly, the size of table is more and would increase with addition of further column. Secondly, a simple select would become complex. Like select employee name whose salary is greater than 1000.

Comment: @Utsav If I use that way for store backup data, Is it ok? (only for backup)

Comment: @user3099298 let it be for backup or anything, for your 300 columns, think that every row in a normalized table will consume 300 rows in your structure. Then for 1000's of data? Moreover, backup will be one day used by you (That's why you backup right?)

Comment: The disadvantage is you get fired, or an advantage, if you don't like the job

Comment: This is often called [Entity–attribute–value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

Comment: This is often called `Everything is a Varchar Model`

Answer (score 2):

On seeing the table structure, it would be easy for you to find out advantages and disadvantages. In short, the second structure is not wise!

1. It contains redundant data. Not a normalized one!
2. You will end up with too many rows.
3. You need to query too many times to fetch a single information.

For your 3rd question. No it is not a good practice. But may I know why you want to create table in this way?

Comment: I created form that form has more than 300 fields, to store those data I thought to go with that way

Comment: 300 Fields in single table is not a good approach. Why don't you initially normalize the tables? http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Comment: maybe you are storing 300 columns because you are saving data goofy

Comment: @user3099298, if you post your 300 columns you would get some hints how to normalize them into different tables... So: 1) read about normalization, 2) try to find some ideas yourself, 3) start a new question